# how to detect water level using NodeMCU in overhead tank?

Tags: sensor, nodemcu, water

I am making a simple water level alarm connected to my V2 NodeMCU. Using the principle of water conductivity.

[image]

Two wires with stripped ends are dipped into the tank. As soon as the water level reaches a certain height, the alarm starts buzzing as the circuit gets completed.

Instead of the buzzer, I need a Blynk notification. Can I do the following:

1. Power a wire with 5V dc supply and dip one end of this wire in water.
2. Take a second wire and also dip one end of this wire in water close to 1st one.
3. Plug another end of second wire in D6 pin on NodeMCU, setting it as INPUT.
4. In the Arduino code, read HIGH and LOW on D6 pin.

Will this work? Or is there a better way?

The overhead tank is about 30 - 40 feet away from NodeMCU. Will this work at that distance?

---

**Sensor 2:** I also have a water flow rate monitor using Hall effect. This sensor will also be used at 30 - 40 feet distance. How do I make the signals from the sensor travel that distance?

Comment: The pictures and links to some other product are irrelevant and are cluttering the post. Unless it is a spam in disguise.

Comment: *How... I want, I need...* But you have no clue how. I suggest you go search on instructables.com for similar projects. Your question is too unfocussed, it would require writing an answer same size as a book to make you design this **or** someone doing it for you and then giving you the design. That doesn't work on this site.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The link is unaffiliated, only mentioned to aid the question. I will be happy to remove it if required.

Comment: @jerrymouse I do believe it has a little relevance to the question and making it harder to read.

Comment: I am editing the question

Comment: Made the question more focused with brevity.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sell the NodeMCU on eBay
2. With the money, buy a float switch
3. Connect the float switch to the two wires that you now show going to the water tank

Voilà!

Comment: But how will I get notification on Blynk iot mobile app? I need nodemcu to wire in IFTTT.